# Only light appearance color returned from [UIColor colorNamed:] even though traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle = Dark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, ios-darkmode

I am working on adding iOS 13 Dark Mode support to my iOS 11+ app. The works great using named / dynamic colors all over the app.

However, when using [UIColor colorNamed:] in a custom class always the light color version (`#ffffff` / white) is returned instead of the dark version (`#000000` / black):

```
// Some ViewController
CustomClass *custom = [customClass alloc] initWithTraitCollection:self.traitCollection]; 

- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];
    custom.traitCollection = self.traitCollection;
}


// CustomClass
- (void)initWithTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.traitCollection = traitCollection;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)doSomething {    
    NSLog(@"CustomClass UIStyle: %@", (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyleDark ? @"dark" : (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyleLight ? @"light" : @"unspecified")));

    // Trying to get the color in three different ways (normal + specify traitCollection explicitly)
    UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorNamed:@"whiteOrBlack"];
    UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorNamed:@"whiteOrBlack" inBundle:nil compatibleWithTraitCollection:self.traitCollection];

    __block UIColor *color3 = color1;
    [self.traitCollection performAsCurrentTraitCollection:^{
         color3 = [UIColor colorNamed:@"whiteOrBlack"];
    }];

    // Output
    NSLog(@"   color1: %@", [self colorAsHexString:color1]);
    NSLog(@"   color2: %@", [self colorAsHexString:color2]);
    NSLog(@"   color3: %@", [self colorAsHexString:color3]);
}


// Output
CustomClass UIStyle: dark
   #ffffff
   #ffffff
   #ffffff
```

It does not matter if I specify the `traitCollection`/`UIUserInterfaceStyle` explictly or not. Only the light color is returned, even if `UIUserInterfaceStyleDark` is active.

**Am I missing something?**

**Is there any other way so explicitly specify which color value I would like to access?**

Comment: kindly add CustomClass init method.

Comment: Done. I have stripped everything from the init method beside setting `self.traitCollection` and the problem is still the same. `CustomClass` is a direct `NSObject` subclass. Even if there would be some wired code in `init` which messes up the `traitCollection`, if `traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle` is Dark just before requesting the color, the dark color should be returned, shouldn't it?

Comment: created own demo project and it is working fine. can you add whiteOrBlack definition

Comment: what is the value of self.traitCollection before creating a CustomClass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UIColor` that you are fetching from the asset catalog is *dynamic*. That means that the values of its RGB components depend on the value of `[UITraitCollection currentTraitCollection]`. Each time you ask for the components, the color resolves itself based on the `currentTraitCollection`.

You didn't show the implementation of your `-colorAsHexString:` method, but it must be getting the RGB components from the color, somehow.

Therefore, you want to call `-colorAsHexString:` at a time when you have set the `currentTraitCollection`, like this:

```
    UIColor *dynamicColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"whiteOrBlack"];

    [self.traitCollection performAsCurrentTraitCollection:^{
         NSLog(@"Color: %@", [self colorAsHexString:dynamicColor]);
    }];
```

(Even better, you could put the call to `performAsCurrentTraitCollection` inside the implementation of `-colorAsHexString:`, if that makes sense in your specific case.)

Here's how to get a resolved, non-dynamic color for a specific trait collection:

```
    UIColor *dynamicColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"whiteOrBlack"];
    UIColor *resolvedColor = [dynamicColor resolvedColorWithTraitCollection:self.traitCollection];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Kurt! I assumed that using `[UIColor colorNamed:` within `self.traitCollection performAsCurrentTraitCollection:` would result in a `UIColor` instance with a *fixed* color value. But as you pointed out this is not true. I fixed this by creating a *fixed* color by using `fixedColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor colorNamed:colorName].CGColor]` inside `self.traitCollection performAsCurrentTraitCollection:`. Do you want to add this to your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: That works, but there's an easier way -- added a note about it.